# Could the Apollo lunar ascent stage have separated from the descent stage before touchdown in an emergency?

Tags: apollo-program, lunar-landing, abort, launch-escape-system

In case the Apollo Lunar module had approached the landing site at way too high velocity, could the ascent stage have separated and returned to the command module before a crash? Thus performing a task similar to a launch abort tower. One challenge would be to synch with the orbit of the command module.

Comment: Did you consider googling "apollo lm abort" before asking this question?

Comment: I believe that Apollo 10 did just this: used the descent stage to approach close to the surface, then jettisoned it and used the ascent stage to return to orbit.

Comment: @jamesqf I just never understood that Apollo 10 returned with the ascent stage only. From answers here I see that they could. So while Armstrong manually searched for a safer landing spot until running on the fumes (as the story is often popularly told), he all the time had the option to abort to the orbiting command module?

Comment: Yes, I believe if the descent stage had expended its fuel, he could have aborted. as long as he was to the left of the ascent engine curve in the figure.  It does get questionable near zero altitude....

Comment: In fact, Apollo 11 wasn't "running on fumes". The time being counted down during the final approach (something less than 30 seconds left when Eagle touched down) was the time until the mission rules called for a mandatory abort using the ascent stage, not time until the lander fell out of the sky.

Comment: Correction: the time countdown was to the "bingo" call, at which point the rules were "land in the next 20 seconds or abort". If they were only 50 feet up at bingo they'd press on. They were about 15 seconds from bingo at touchdown, with over 700 pounds of fuel remaining in the descent tanks. See the annotation at 102:44:45 here: https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/a11.landing.html

Comment: @RussellBorogove So, Armstrong was looking for bingo as in five craters in a row? *(I'm a bit evil, I know, and wasteful on this site)*. Great to learn that there were so many abort options built into the Apollo missions. A luxury one can only afford on Moon missions, I suppose.

Comment: @LocalFluff: From what I've read, the Apollo 10 descent stage purposely didn't have enough fuel to land, let alone return to orbit, because it was believed that otherwise the crew would go ahead and land anyway.

Comment: @jamesqf The idea that an Apollo crew would go off-script and decide to land on a whim is absurd, verging on insulting.

Comment: @RussellBorogove But could they (Apollo 10) have? And be recovered. Maybe not on purpose, but landing as part of a mission abort plan. Landing in order to await the right time to launch to the orbiting module.

Comment: According to Apollo By The Numbers, the Apollo 10 LM had a full load of fuel in the descent stage and about half the usual load in the ascent stage. They could have landed, but not have re-launched. I can't envision any emergency scenario in which landing the LM would make the situation better.

Comment: @Russell Borogove: I can't see the idea as absurd, let alone insulting, since I probably would have done the same thing.  Regardless, I don't know whether or not it's true, only that it is so stated in accounts I've read, and with Gene Cernan quoted as having said "A lot of people thought about the kind of people we were: "Don't give those guys an opportunity to land, 'cause they might!"

Comment: @LocalFluff: But if the LM is in orbit, there are always times (roughly once per orbit) when it could make a burn to match orbits with the CM, and use much less deltaV than departing the surface.

Comment: Cernan was LMP, not commander, and has been described as having a dry sense of humor. I don't doubt that Cernan and Stafford thought about it and joked about it, but I seriously doubt they would have done it even if it were possible. There appears to have been some discussion of making 10 the moon landing, and Stafford was against taking that risk, since there was a lot of LM shakedown and lunar mascon mapping left to do. ABTN also says A10's ascent stage *thrust* was about half of the other LMs; I'm trying to figure out why that was.

Comment: Cernan, in his book The Last Man On The Moon, says at a couple of points that the LM for A10 was "still too heavy to guarantee safe margins for a Moon landing" -- i.e. that weight-saving engineering measures for the LM hadn't been completed. Apollo By The Numbers puts its dry weight at 200 lbs more than A11's LM -- about 2% difference. Nowhere in the book does he suggest that he or Stafford considered going rogue and landing Snoopy.

Answer (score 32):

Yes.  There is a lot of good information in this [presentation](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.207.7507&rep=rep1&type=pdf) from the June 1966 Apollo Lunar Landing Mission Symposium relative to landing flight design including abort planning.  The crucial figure is this one:

[image]

which shows the capability of the ascent engine to abort all the way down to landing.  It assumes a 4 second delay to separate the landing stage.

As far as returning to the orbit of the command module, [the Apollo Experience Report - Abort Planning document](http://klabs.org/history/apollo_experience_reports/tn-d6847_apollo_abort_planning.pdf) explains on page 24 (33 of the pdf) that the Lunar Module would attempt to attain a safe orbit and the Command Module would rendezvous with it.

Comment: In an emergency, could the 4-second delay have been foregone and the ascent engine fired immediately upon staging?

Answer (score 12):

That maneuver was called "fire in the hole". See the wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_in_the_hole). According to this NASA [paper](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a15/a15mrp9.pdf) there was an extra "fire-in-the-hole shield". During Apollo 5, 9 and 10 there was a test of "fire-in-the-hole", see [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_5) ,  [2](http://www.thespacereview.com/article/2462/1) and [3](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4029/Apollo_09a_Summary.htm). The LM test of Apollo 5 was done unmanned.

The insignia of the mission Apollo 5 was designed by Grumman engineers to show the fire in the hole test.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for adding the picture of the mission patch. My answer looks so much better now. The patch insistently shows the simultaneous firing of the decent and the ascent stage.

Comment: I found no information about a fire in the hole test during the missions Apollo 6, 7, 8 and 10. Did they do only two fire in the hole tests? I suspect there were more than only two.

Comment: Apollo 6 didn't have a real LM, 7 & 8 had no LM,  10 staged the LM in low lunar orbit.  So 10 maybe.

Comment: I found it in the german wikipedia, there was a in flight separation of the ascent stage of the LM during the Apollo 10 mission.

Comment: Apollo 5 was an unmanned mission without a Command/Service Module. But who wore the mission patch? Were the patches made only for use as a souvenir?

Comment: Mission patches get handed out to a lot of people. Some collect them, some sew them on a jacket.

Comment: Note also that the patch shows (correctly) that the descent stage had no landing gear.